# My Ubuntu installation (triple booting Ubuntu 13.04, WinXP and Win7) made my Win7 impossible to boot

Tags: boot, 13.04, windows-7, dual-boot

I really hope this question is appropriate for this place, since I have absolutely no idea who to ask, or what to do.

When I first tried to install Ubuntu (well, second time, but the previous time was irrelevant, I installed and uninstalled it with no problem, I couldn't connect to the internet on Ubuntu back then due to my very old modem), I used a USB flash drive. Apparently, there was some kind of a problem in the flash drive, and the installation didn't complete. It stopped halfway through every time I tried it. Ever since I half-installed it, every time I tried to boot Windows 7, it failed to boot. I have no GUI boot enabled, so the only indication of booting is 3 teal dashes in the upper left part of the screen. It starts booting and then suddenly the top of the screen (where those teal dashes are) becomes scrambled, like when you move around a cartridge inside an old game console.

My Windows XP partition works perfectly, and all my files are fine - nothing was lost. When I boot, the first thing that launches is the GNU GRUB bootloader that gives me options between Ubuntu and Windows 7. If I choose Windows 7, it gives me another boot manager (the one that I used previously to choose between XP and 7). If I choose Windows XP (listed as an "older version of Windows"), everything works fine. If I choose Windows 7, the problem that I mention pops up. It just stays scrambled like that no matter how much I wait.

I tried running the repair tools. I ran the startup problem detector and it detected no problems. Someone suggested that it might be a problem with GRUB.

Any ideas? Thanks.

P.S: Apologies for not pointing it out, but after the USB installation failed, I managed to install Ubuntu successfully using a DVD, and I have been using it for like a month already. I have been in the mood for some games on my Win7 partition, so I decided to find a way to restore it (the Win7 itself, the files themselves are fine, as I said).

Answer (score 0):

Really a Windows issue.

Windows can only boot thru one partition with the boot flag (or active partition in Windows). So Windows 7 installed its boot loader into your XP partition and that is what you are using to boot with. Once grub has chainloaded to the Windows boot loader, grub is not involved, so not a grub issue.

Did you at some point resize the Windows 7 partition? Often better to use Windows tools, but the installer or gparted often works. But you need to immediately boot Windows 7, so it can run chkdsk and make its repairs to its new partition size.
You may just need to run chkdsk from a Windows repair console on your Windows 7 partition. Do not use XP's chkdsk for that as it will  convert partition to XP type not Windows 7 type.

Comment: I now have 3 partitions. The oldest one being the Windows XP partition, then another Windows 7 one, and the new Ubuntu one. I resized a partition with no OS/boot-related files to create the Ubuntu partition (a big partition where I store my files, unrelated to the XP and 7 partitions). I never resized the partitions that contained XP or 7.

Comment: How am I supposed to run chkdsk if I can't boot into Win7, and if I can't use XP's chkdsk, by the way?